# Como usar evento de botões dinamicamente criados para redirecionar para outra página ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Eu estou tentando chamar o evento dos botões que foram criados dinamicamente com um foreach

```
public void adicionarComanda()
{
    List<Comanda> lc = ControllerComanda.getComanda();

    foreach (Comanda comanda in lc)
    {
        Button bt = new Button();
        bt.Text = comanda.nome_Pessoa;
        bt.CssClass = "botoes";
        bt.Click += btnNome1_Click;
        bt.CommandArgument = comanda.nome_Pessoa;              

        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Controls.Add(bt);
        ulBotoes.Controls.Add(li);
    }

}
```

E o evento:

```
protected void btnNome1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nomePessoa = (sender as Button).CommandArgument;
    Session["currentUser"] = nomePessoa.ToString();
    Response.Redirect("~/Mobile/Pages/produtosCategoria.aspx");
}
```

Como eu poderia resolver esse problema e fazer o evento funcionar e eu ser redirecionado para a página desejada? Muito obrigado a todos!

Comment: Seu sistema roda em WebForms certo ?

Comment: Sim Érik, é em webforms

Comment: Seu código esta correto, acabei de copia-lo, e consegui faze-lo funcionar corretamente. Em qual evento está chamando o método `adicionarComanda`? Pode ser que um postback esteja ocorrendo entre a criação doa seus controles e o clique, fazendo com que eles percam o evento. Se puder, poste o código que faz a chamada do método que cria os controles.

Comment: Olá Marcus tudo bem? Então, eu uso esse botão aqui para adicionar uma comanda ao banco de dados:

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {   
            Conexao.inserirComanda(nome);
            txtNome.Text = "";
            txtNome.Focus();
        }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            adicionarComanda();
        }
E então no page Load eu chamo aquele método adicionar comanda. Porém após eu inserir, eu tenho que dar um reload na página para aparecer os botoes que foram criados.Como faria pra eu inserir e já aparecer?

Comment: Opa Marcus, eu resolvi o problema! Era só eu colocar um Reponse.Redirect() no método de inserir comanda para a página atual, que daí os botões são gerados! Mas muito obrigado!

Comment: Coloque a solução aqui como resposta, ela pode ajudar outras pessoas!

Answer (score 1):

Os eventos são chamados depois do Page_Load, logo a solução foi no evento de adicionar os botões colocar um Response.Redirect() para a mesma página no evento que adiciona os botões dinamicos.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string nome = txtNome.Text.Trim();

        ControllerComanda.inserirComanda(nome);

        txtNome.Text = "";
        txtNome.Focus();

        Response.Redirect("~/Mobile/Pages/paginaComandas.aspx");
    }
```

Chamando a mesma página após a inserção, fará que ocorrá novamente o page load e criará após isso os botões.